# compare two int array and output new and former items

Tags: java, compare

I'm really new to Java. I need to know between two arrays the new items and former items. 
example:

```
A1= {4,5,6};
A2={5,6,7};
result: new item is 7
    former item is 4.
```

I try this code with no results:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List; 
Integer[] s1 = {4, 5, 6};
  Integer[] s2 = {5,6,7};
  List<Integer> s1List = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s1));
  for (Integer s : s2) {
    if (s1List.contains(s)) {
      s1List.remove(s);
    } 
    else {
      s1List.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println("nouveaux items =" + s1List);

  }
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What error or unexpected behavior are you currently getting in your code?

Comment: Don't you need 2 lists? one for former items and one for new ones?

Comment: Are you assuming pre-sorted lists?

Comment: please post at least a compilable version of code.

Comment: it looks pretty simple, but I don;t know what you are trying to acheive

Comment: @NimChimpsky Yes Exactly..

Answer (score 2):

What I understand you are trying is:

```
Integer[] s1 = {3, 4, 5, 6};
Integer[] s2 = {3, 5, 6, 7};
List<Integer> newItems = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(s1));
newItems.removeAll(Arrays.asList(s2));
List<Integer> formerItems = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(s2));
formerItems.removeAll(Arrays.asList(s1));
System.out.println("New items: " + newItems);
System.out.println("Former items: " + formerItems);
```

Outputs:

```
New items: [7]
Former items: [4]
```

Comment: removeAll is the way to go. What remains in the final list is what the OP wants.

Comment: this give me this error: the method addall collection extends integer, is not applicable for the arguments list> int[]. Here's my declaration int[] s1 = new int[3];
int[] s2 = new int[3];
s1[0]=4;
s1[1]=5;
s1[2]=6;
s2[0]=5;
s2[1]=6;
s2[2]=7;

Comment: @user2216280 my bad, I fixed the problems

Answer (score 0):

U are almost there ,Just Add two list s1List is with old items and for new items new list

```
List<Integer> s1List = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s1));
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList();

for (Integer s : s2) {
if (s1List.contains(s)) {
   s1List.remove(s);
 } 
 else {
   newList.add(s);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two arrays a1 and a2, you former items will be the ones present in the a1 and not in a2 and new will be just the opposite. Assuming this is what you meant, the function `newItem(a1, a2)` finds the items present in a2 but not in a1. The `formerItems()` just uses `newItems()` with arrays swapped as the logic remains same.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FormerAndLast {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] s1 = { 4, 5, 6 };
        Integer[] s2 = { 5, 6, 7 };

        System.out.println("nouveaux items =" + newItems(s1, s2));

        System.out.println("former items =" + formerItems(s1, s2));
    }

    private static List<Integer> formerItems(Integer[] s1, Integer[] s2) {
        return newItems(s2, s1);
    }

    private static List<Integer> newItems(Integer[] a1, Integer[] a2) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(a1);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(a2);

        List<Integer> newItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (Integer i : list2) {
            if (!list1.contains(i))
                newItems.add(i);
        }

        return newItems;
    }
}
```

> PS: Executable code in Java should reside in functions such as main
>   (except initialization)